# Get Coordinates of Voronoi Polygon Vertices

Tags: qgis, polygon, coordinates, voronoi-thiessen

Is there any chance to get the exact coordinatas of the voronoi polygons? I am using Qgis software and I have the "center" (redpoint) of the polygons and I would like to export the polygons corners coordinates.[image]

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include software, version, etc.? (Unless you are looking for a non-specific solution.) Regardless, your question could use some more information about what you want.

Comment: Welcome to GSE.  You'll need to edit the Question to answer some questions: Which voronoi polygons?  In what format?  With what software?  In what context?

Comment: Sorry I have modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In qgis, the points of the boundary of your polygon are called "nodes".

You can use vector > geometry tools > extract nodes to get those points